# Webpack for component library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, libraries

Let's imagine the following structure for a component library:

```
/my-library
  - /src
    - /components
      - Button.js (ES6 + React)
      - Anchor.js (ES6 + React)
    - index.js (ES6)
```

Now I want to prepare this library for production, and this is how my distribution folder should look like

```
/my-library
  - /dist
    - /components
      - Button.js (Target: Node, Compiled to ES5 using babel)
      - Anchor.js (Target: Node, Compiled to ES5 using babel)
    - index.js (Target: browser, compiled and minified with webpack)
```

Currently I achieve that with two tasks:

1 - One task to "copy" contents from `src/components` and compile with babel.

2 - Another task to run webpack on `src/index.js`.

I want to simplify this process and I was told that webpack could be used as the only tool for this process. And this kind of makes sense because `src/index.js` will go through all the components anyways, why do that twice?

The problem I'm facing is how to provide two different targets for Webpack (node and browser). I think I have an idea how to prepare my entries to output all the components individually, but how to also provide the minified version in a **single** run?

Any ideas how such webpack configuration should look like?

Answer (score 2):

You need [rollup.js](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Command-Line-Interface) and not webpack.

For yours components (Button.js, Anchor.js) use [rollup-plugin-multi-entry](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-multi-entry)

Example (without multiple entries. Do it by docs from link below)

```
rollup -c build/rollup.config.js && uglifyjs dist/index.js -cm --comments -o dist/index.min.js
```

(it's command need add to package.json -> scripts -> "build")

Example rollup.config.js

```
const buble = require('rollup-plugin-buble')
const flow = require('rollup-plugin-flow-no-whitespace')
const cjs = require('rollup-plugin-commonjs')
const node = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve')
const replace = require('rollup-plugin-replace')

module.exports = {
  entry: 'src/index.js',
  dest: 'dist/vue-router.js',
  format: 'umd',
  moduleName: 'VueRouter',
  plugins: [replace({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"development"'
  }), flow(), node(), cjs(), buble()]
}
```

Comment: Thansk for sharing that. But I have a developer environment for my organization, so I don't expose the scripts so that I can easily work on upgrades. I'm not familiar with rollup and most of my organization uses webpack. I'm assuming there is a plugin for rollup to uglify content? I don't think I will be able to move away from webpack that easily. But I will definitely look into rollup.

Comment: I think, you can do 2 webpack configs: first for browser and second for node with multiple entries ( entry: [ './components/Button.js', './components/Anchor.js' ] or use ./components/*.js' )

Comment: And add script to package json for build with 2 webpack configs.

Comment: correct they support glob for their entry. But the problem is the output target, which is not "per-entry". The config for output is only one.

Comment: two different webpack configs I would say it is the same limitation I have today with my two tasks that will run babel twice.

Comment: "Rollup for libraries, webpack for projects.." - why?

Comment: @AlexShtorov I have to disagree with you, both resolve the "bundling" and even if rollup solves easier the bundling for a library, I think the question is how with webpack, this could be solved.